# How to run same test for different URLs in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have around 7 test files and in total 60 test cases that needs to be run for 2 URLs.

Way 1 is: loop on each test - so each test will run for 2 URLs and URL I am passing as argument. But that requires forEach in each test.

Way 2: I tried opening URL in beforeEach() like below:

```
describe('Your Finance Page tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    brands.forEach(function (brand) {
      openUrl(brand)
    });
  });
```

It is opening brand for each test but running test for 1 brand only. Like before each test it opens brand A, then brand B and run test on brand B only.

Is there any better way to do this other than writing forEach in each test?

Comment: Run the suite multiple times with a different CYPRESS_BASE_URL?

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop will *probably* work if it's external to the `beforeEach()` and the `it()` blocks.

This article [Dynamic Tests From Cypress Fixture](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/dynamic-tests-from-fixture/)  describes the pattern in detail.

```js
const brandUrls = [...]

describe('Test each brand', () => {

  brandUrls.forEach(brandUrl => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit(brandUrl)
    })

    it(`tests url ${brandUrl}`, () => {
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

Note, your brands must be either hard-coded or read from a fixture using `require()` or `import` at the top of the spec.

As for applying it to multiples specs, yes add it to each spec (for simplicity).

---

**cypress-each package**

The [cypress-each](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-each) package does something similar, but has expanded capabilities.

```js
import 'cypress-each'

// create a separate test for each brand
const brands = [...]

it.each(brands)('test %s brand, (brand) => {
  cy.visit(brand)
  ...  // assertions
})
```